# Spring Java Conversion exception

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I am trying to store an `EnumSet` object into my neo4j db.  However, I get this exception:

`org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.util.LinkedHashSet<?> to type java.util.EnumSet<?> for value '[READ, WRITE, OPTIONAL]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Collection type: java.util.EnumSet`

Is there some way to substitute the the `EnumSet` with something else?  Or, does anyone know a work around?

I've tried making the set as a `HashSet`, but I lose the methods that `EnumSet` gives me, such as `noneOf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can write your own custom converter and register it in app ctx. Follow the [documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).

Comment: Thanks, looking into it.